# What does -keep class do in ProGuard

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I know that keep class is suppose to keep the class.

1. But let's say if I keep class on a specific class, will it not obfuscate the said class?

   -keep class com.myproject.activities.**
2. What is the difference between `keep class` vs `keep public class`

Answer (score 3):

I know this is too late to answer but this may helpfull for someone.
From Guard Square documentation about **-keep**

> **-keep** Specifies classes and class members (fields and methods) to be preserved as entry points to your code. For example, in order to keep an application, you can specify the main class along with its main method. In order to process a library, you should specify all publicly accessible elements.

You can check below links for more details about ProGuard specifires.
https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage

http://omgitsmgp.com/2013/09/09/a-conservative-guide-to-proguard-for-android/

Comment: This definition is not clear. It tells you what are some of the typical examples of '-keep' but not what it does. Does it not obfuscate and not shrink? Why would someone want to use '-keep' when '-keepnames' is available?